# Editar en la misma fila de la tabla con Vue.js-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una practica basada en CRUD, utilizando el framework de CSS, Bootstrap y el framework de JS, Vue.js. La incógnita que me ha surgido es como editar un dato en la misma fila de la tabla donde se encuentra contenida la información anteriormente registrada.

Hasta ahora, he logrado hacerlo aparte, con un par de inputs pero no es algo con lo que estoy conforme. De igual forma, reutilizo esas mismas cajas de texto para hacer el registro de datos.

```
<div class="container" id="main">
    <br>
    <h1 class="fw-bold">CRUD</h1>
    <p class="fst-normal">Sistema CRUD encapsulado en una tabla dinamica que permite agregar, cancelar, editar y
        eliminar cada registro.</p>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="View(1, 0)">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3h-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3v3a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-3h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3v-3z"/>
        </svg>
        Agregar
    </button>
    <hr>
    <div v-if="data.length != 0" class="justify-content-center">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre (s)</th>
                    <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
                    <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                    <th scope="col">Eliminar</th>
                    <th scope="col">Modificar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="i">
                    <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="Eliminar(i)" v-bind:disabled="enabled">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="View(2, i)" v-bind:disabled="enabled">Modificar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-else>
        La tabla está vacía.
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row" v-show="enabled">
        <h1 class="fw-bold">{{label}}</h1>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre (s)" v-model="inputName">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" v-model="inputLastname">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Teléfono"></td>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-success" v-if="label == 'Registro'" @click="Registrar">Enviar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success" v-else @click="Modf">Editar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="cancelarRegistro">Cancelar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Para visualizar las cajas de texto en algunos de los casos para agregar o editar, uso este metodo:

```
View: function (option, index) {
        if (option == 1) {
            this.label = "Registro";
        } else if (option == 2) {
            this.label = "Modificar";
            this.position = index;
        }
        this.enabled = true;
}
```

Y para modificar uso el método:

```
Modf: function () {
        if (this.validateInput()) {
            this.data[this.position].name = this.inputName;
            this.data[this.position].lastname = this.inputLastname;
            this.enabled = false;
            this.clearFields();
            this.Alert("El usuario de modificó correctamente");
        } else {
            this.Alert("Campos obligatorios");
        }
}
```

He escuchado sobre la directiva *v-slot:cell* pero no he logrado entender su correcto funcionamiento y su sintaxis con HTML.